# Volume of a rotated region?

Tags: calculus, geometry, integration

How can I find the volume of the solid generated when the region enclosed by $y=0, x=0, x=1$ and $(1+e^{-2x})^{0.5}$ is rotated through $360^\circ$ about the x axis?

Comment: Sorry, fairly big change to the question there... I've replaced the 3 with an e.

Comment: That makes no difference with the method you'll use to find the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that I understand what you mean, but try this:
$$\pi\int_0^1 f(x)^2 \text{ d}x$$
where $f(x)$ in this case is your function $(1+e^{-2x})^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: I see that Matthews answer explains why this is the way to go.

Comment: why pi not 2 pi?

Comment: Because the area of a circle is given by $\pi r^2$.

Comment: Brilliant, I get it know. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of an object can be found by integrating the cross-sectional area through all cross-sections.

A cross-section of this solid, taken perpendicularly to the $x$-axis at a distance $x$ from the $y$-axis, is a disk with radius $(1+e^{-2x})^{0.5}$.  Express the area of this disk as a function of $x$, and then integrate this function from $x=0$ to $x=1$.